# How to commit a Git file locally?

Tags: git, svn, github, commit, git-commit

I want to commit a file to a Git repository locally for my sample projects

**Failed Attempts to Commit File Locally**

```
Divyanshu (master +) asteroids $ git commit -m "Fire one bullet at a time"

fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': Unable to create 'C:/Users/Divyanshu/Desktop/dktop/focus/
Udacity/Git-hub/version-control/repositories/asteroids/.git/refs/heads/master.lock': 
File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g. an editor opened by 'git 
commit'. Please make sure all processes are terminated then try again. If it still fails,
a git process may have crashed in this repository earlier: remove the file manually to 
continue.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Close all the Git terminal or any other editors that are accessing files of that repository
- Go to this path: 
      `C:/Users/Divyanshu/Desktop/dktop/focus/Udacity/Git-hub/version-control/repositories/asteroids/.git/refs/heads/master.lock`
- Delete the file named `master.lock`
- Run your Git terminal again in administrator mode

Then you should try commiting again!